# Forbidden Access with RavenDB 5 Client

Tags: c#, linux, database-connection, ravendb, ravendb5

I am trying to connect to my cloud based ravendb database using the ravendb client.
I have no issues on my local machine, however whenever I attempt to connect on my production game server, I receive the following error:

> Forbidden access

```
{"Type":"InvalidAuth","Message":"This server requires client certificate for authentication, but none was provided by the client. Did you forget to install the certificate?"}
```

Please note that the production server runs on a stripped down version of ubuntu linux.

I verified that the certificate was shipped with the build image. I verified the certificate is valid and works. I know it works properly because on my local environment it works without issues.

I have the following code:

```
public static class DocumentStoreHolder
{
    private const string CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD = "-snip-";
    private static string CERTIFICATE_PATH = Path.GetFullPath("certificate.pfx");

    public static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate()
    {
        return new X509Certificate2(CERTIFICATE_PATH, CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD);
    }
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        var certificate = GetCertificate();
        if (certificate.HasPrivateKey)
        {
            ksLog.Debug("Private key exists.");
        }
        else
        {
            ksLog.Debug("Private key does not exist.");
        }
        LazyStore = new Lazy<IDocumentStore>(() =>
        {
            var store = new DocumentStore
            {
                Urls = new[] { "-snip-" },
                Database = "-snip-",
                Certificate = certificate,
            };

            return store.Initialize();
        });

    }

    private static Lazy<IDocumentStore> LazyStore;

    public static IDocumentStore Store => LazyStore.Value;
}
```

On the production server "Private Key Exists" is output. so we know that the certificate is loaded into memory properly.

Please note that I am using .net Framework 4.8. I am running the latest build of RavenDB Client.

I reached out to support and they had the following to say:
`Basically it's about the X509 certificate's private key. In a lot of platform you need to allow the app to load that certificate explicitly e.g. by providing its thumbprint`

Unfortunately that didn't help me much.

If anyone else has suggestions or things I can try, it would be most appreciated..!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a chance there is some kind of utility on or between your prod server and the RavenDB Cloud instance?

The code seems fine and last time I saw such an error was when the Security Team in the company enabled software filtering out the client certificate sent to the server through the network.